# Using str_replace to test for existence in an array

Tags: php, if-statement, str-replace

I have the following function

```
function blah($string) {
    $match = array('red', 'green', 'blue');
    $replace = array('1', '1,', '0');
    return str_replace($match, $replace $string);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is, if the input is not in the match array, return 0.

Since this is only used on the back end once/day, performance isn't the biggest issue but since i'm still learning PHP, I'd like to understand the proper way of doing this.

Any help is really appreciated!  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following code:

```
function approved($input) {
$match = array('red','green','blue');
if(in_array(strtolower($input), $match)) {
   return 1;
} else {
    return 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I suggest using PHP's built-in [`in_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function instead of writing your own.

Comment: so just to be clear, into the match array, I ONLY put what i want to be returned as 1?

Comment: Seems that returned 0 for everything in the array,  the input array is a set of categories which I auto approve while 0 goes up for manual review.

Comment: @Mike: Do you really need to return 0 or 1? Would boolean true or false work just as well for you? If so, it would simplify things and allow you to use the return value from in_array() without casting to an integer. I suspect that might be the root of your problem.

Comment: the returned value does need to be either 1 or 0, in my case 1 = approved , 0 = pending,

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
function blah($string) {
    $matches = array('red', 'green');        
    return in_array($string, $matches);
}
```

Another thing I might add is that you should avoid using a function like `str_replace` (which, at a glance, would mean replacing strings) for something that is testing existence as it might confuse other programmers (or yourself) when reading the code.

Comment: perhaps i'm totally missing the fundamentals, but what actually returns either 1 or 0?  everything was returned as 0.

Comment: How are you calling the function? `echo blah('red');` should print `1`.

Comment: $approved = approved(catinput(preg_replace('/^A-z0-9\s/', "", trim($product['category']))));   (catinput is pretty much the same match/replace to take all the preset categories and change them to the list of categories that i want -- such as car -> cars, etc)

Comment: just checked vardump and it returns a blank

Comment: Ensure all your variables are holding what you think.  For example, call `approved('red')` (where 'red' is a category you know is in there) before passing it a big complicated expression.

Comment: the match array is the result of the replacement array of catinput, so it has to be there, catinput on its own has been tested and is working.